# Had Doc Brown been looking for Marty all week?

Tags: back-to-the-future

During the opening scene of BttF, Doc calls his own lab to tell Marty about the experiment he wants to show him that night.

From a [transcript](https://sfy.ru/transcript/back_to_the_future_ts):

> Marty: You know, Doc, you left your equipment on **all week**.

This sounds like neither Doc nor Marty have been to the lab recently. This is further substantiated with Marty's surprise when all the clocks start chiming.

**Did Doc--presumably through time travel--know to call that specific day and time to talk to Marty, had he been calling all week looking for him, or was it luck that Marty decided to drop by when Doc happened to call?**

Comment: Doc hadn't time travelled at that point. The first experiment with time travel was afterwards, when they sent Einstein one minute into the future.

Answer (score 2):

As I recall from the movie, Marty gets into Doc's lab by just letting himself in, even though Doc was not there to invite him in. That implies that Marty and Doc had somehow agreed in advance that Marty could come in. Perhaps they normally meet every week at that time, or they had agreed a week ago for Marty to visit at that time.

Comment: If you had a source confirming this that'd be great